# However to retrieve a missing commit after git merge

Tags: github

what is correct steps for me to merge one branch to my local feature branch? I use `merge` command . however, after merging, one local commit does not display for some reason but I am able to retrieve the hex from GitHub.

```
git checkout -b feature/local
# make change
git add <file>
git commit -m "file commit message"
git push

git checkout feature/working_parent
git pull
git checkout feature/local
git merge feature/working_parent
git push
```

the commit "file commit message" does not apply on feature/local anymore

Comment: This seems not possible.  How did you verify that the commit in question were there before/after the merge?

Comment: i check the commit history by hex on GitHub web. because I am sure I push the question commit